# Models don't show up in the django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My model does not show up in the Django admin.

I don't understand this. I have been doing this several times before:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from djntra.models import Thing


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
```

I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in my code. You need to use `admin.site.register()`. The **site** was missing.

This works:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from djntra.models import Thing


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
```